# Progress Bar Doesn't Update On Page

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok so here I have this trouble, my progress bar doesn't work when I apply to `translate: transform` to my `<div>`, without `transform` works perfectly, but I need apply `transform` to `<div>` 'cause I need to move a bit the `<body>'s` position

here the code

```js
//<![CDATA[

$(document).ready(function(){
  
    var getMax = function(){
        return $(document).height() - $(window).height();
    }
  
    var getValue = function(){
        return $(window).scrollTop();
    }
  
    if('max' in document.createElement('progress')){
        // Browser supports progress element
        var progressBar = $('progress');
      
        // Set the Max attr for the first time
        progressBar.attr({ max: getMax() });

        $(document).on('scroll', function(){
            // On scroll only Value attr needs to be calculated
            progressBar.attr({ value: getValue() });
        });
    
        $(window).resize(function(){
            // On resize, both Max/Value attr needs to be calculated
            progressBar.attr({ max: getMax(), value: getValue() });
        });  
    }
    else {
        var progressBar = $('.progress-bar'),
            max = getMax(),
            value, width;
      
        var getWidth = function(){
            // Calculate width in percentage
            value = getValue();          
            width = (value/max) * 100;
            width = width + '%';
            return width;
        }
      
        var setWidth = function(){
            progressBar.css({ width: getWidth() });
        }
      
        $(document).on('scroll', setWidth);
        $(window).on('resize', function(){
            // Need to reset the Max attr
            max = getMax();
            setWidth();
        });
    }
});
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#flat').addClass("active");
$('#progressBar').addClass('flat');

$('#flat').on('click', function(){
$('#progressBar').removeClass().addClass('flat');
$('a').removeClass();
$(this).addClass('active');
$(this).preventDefault();
});

$('#multiple').addClass("active");
$('#progressBar').addClass('multiple');

$('#multiple').on('click', function(){
$('#progressBar').removeClass().addClass('multiple');
$('a').removeClass();    
$(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).preventDefault();    
  });

});
//]]>
```

```css
/* reading position indicator */
progress {
/* Positioning */
position: fixed;
left: 0;
top: 0;
z-index: 101;

/* Dimensions */
width: 100%;
height: 0.28125em;

/* Reset the apperance */
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;

/* Get rid of the default border in Firefox/Opera. */
border: none;

/* For Firefox/IE10+ */
background-color: transparent;

/* For IE10+, color of the progress bar */
color: red;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
background-color: transparent;
}

.flat::-webkit-progress-value {
background-color: green;
}

.flat::-moz-progress-bar {
background-color: green;
}

.multiple::-webkit-progress-value {
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,
transparent 33%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 33%,
rgba(0,0, 0, .1) 66%, transparent 66%),
-webkit-linear-gradient(left, red, orange, yellow, green);
}

.multiple::-moz-progress-bar {
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,
transparent 33%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 33%,
rgba(0,0, 0, .1) 66%, transparent 66%),
-moz-linear-gradient(left, red, orange, yellow, green,);
}

.progress-container {
width: 100%;
background-color: transparent;
position: fixed;
left: 0;
top: 0;
height: 0.28125em;
display: block;
z-index: 101;
}

.progress-bar {
background-color: green;
width: 50%;
display: block;
height: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js'>
</script>
<progress id='progressBar' value='0'>
<div class='progress-container'>
<span class='progress-bar'/>
</div>
</progress>
```

remember's just a progress bar so won't be visible on snippet, can someone help me with this little one?
I don't know how this could be happened, I'm really worried

Comment: You missed a `>`.

Comment: @Zera Edited, now check it out on my blog, doesn't work [https://guialossimpsonspringfield.blogspot.com/], inspect `content-inner <div>` and `progress`

Comment: It works on your [example](https://jsfiddle.net/Zeraora/efqyw1va/).

Comment: @Zera ok but try it applying `translate: transform` to `content-inner <div>'s` in my blog, not works

Comment: Do you mean `transform: translate()`?

Comment: @Zera yes, exact that one, don't know why doesn't work

Comment: The progress bar becomes hidden anyway as you scroll. Shouldn't it be in a fixed position?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210924/discussion-between-federico-migueletto-and-zera).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is just the css property that causes the issue, why don't you remove the transform and try something like `margin: 0 -24px;` instead?